# Ranking the performance of countries (entities) from a panel-based fixed effects regression

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, fixed-effects-model, ranking

I am performing a fixed effects regression analysis on countries, $i$, over a time period $t$ with regressor $X$ and outcome $y$ so that the equation is

$y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_{it} + \epsilon_{it}$

where $\epsilon$ is the error term and \beta is the coefficient of the regressor.

I want to rank countries according to the magnitude and direction in which they influence the result of the regression.

My thought was to take one country, remove it from the dataset, and then run the regression with the dataset sans that country. I could then repeat this for each country and compare and rank the magnitudes of the coefficients across the different iterations.

Would that make statistical sense?

Is there a more efficient alternative?